# Positioning opaque pseudo content behind relatively positioned text

Tags: css, css-position, z-index, background-color

I'm trying to position an opaque black background behind some text, but having trouble as the text is always behind the opaque colour. I can't use z-index as the text is relatively positioned, does anyone know how I can make the text appear on top of the opaque background?

**JS fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/abtuj3xj/

**HTML**

```
<section class="primary" style="background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-640-480-9.jpg');" data-bgimg="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-640-480-9.jpg">
    <div class="item">
        <article>
            <div class="entry">
                <p>A whole bunch of text that goes on top of everything but is relatively positioned</p>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        </article>
    </div> <!-- End div.item -->
    <p class="scroll-down">Scroll down</p>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
section {
    position:relative; text-align: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;
    min-height:100%; color:#fff;
}
.item:after {
    content: ''; position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:0; left:0;
    background-color:#000; opacity:0.3;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I am not understanding your question, however it is still worth a try.

http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/abtuj3xj/1/

```
section {
    position:relative; text-align: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;
    min-height:100%; color:#fff;z-index: -9999;
}

.item:after {
    content: ''; position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; top:0; left:0;
    background-color:#000; opacity:0.3; z-index: -9999;
}
```

Comment: And there was me thinking I couldn't use z-index on relatively positioned block elements! Thanks for that, sorted the problem.